# Why does sound start and fades out until it is not heard anymore? How can I fix this?

Tags: sound

If I start playing music in Spotify or a YouTube video, the sound starts and immediately fades out and cannot be heard anymore. Pavucontrol shows the sound on but nothing can be heard.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of `alsamixer` before and after the mute?

Comment: Does this happen when you listen to an audio file from your PC? Here's some open source Bach to test with: https://www.opengoldbergvariations.org/ Also, can you confirm this happens when you plug earphones into the PC, as opposed to your normal Bluetooth or speaker setup?  Please click [edit] to respond; please don't use Add Comment, instead use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely don know what happened...I'm new to linux...I read your answers, booted back to ubuntu instead of Windows and as soon as I got it, I turned the volume up, took the screen shot of alsamixer, and then went ahead and opened Spotify to have the issue happen...but it didn...I'm currently writing this while listening to some music on Spotify...weird...thanks! I'll keep you posted if it happens again or something changes